# Getting Error after integrating facebook sdk in windows phone 8

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8

I Have integrated facebook sdk in my windows phone 8 app and used facebook controls after downloading from NuGet.
However when I navigate to that facebook page, I get a "TargetInvocationException" and goes to Application Unhandled method where the debugger breaks, and the app crashes.
This is the exception: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll"
Do I need to do anything else after downloading refrences from NuGet?.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown by methods invoked through reflection, but without knowing more about you implementation it will be hard for anyone to help and advise.

Are you able to provide more information, in particular code snippets and details of the inner exception?